# Unable to find outbound socket even with ip_connectionId set

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

I'm working on an app that receives a request over TCP and publishes it to an event queue. It then receives a response from that event queue and sends the response back over the correct TCP connection. The app works when I run it, but I'm trying to write a test to simulate the response flow.

Config:

```
    @Autowired
    private TcpToQueueHandler tcpToQueueHandler;

    @Autowired
    private QueueToTcpHandler queueToTcpHandler;

    // Main config

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow tcpToQueueFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Tcp.inboundAdapter(tcpServerFactory()))
                .handle(tcpToQueueHandler, "handleTcpIn")
                .route("headers['replyChannel']")
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow queueToTcpFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Processor.INPUT)
                .handle(queueToTcpHandler, "handleQueueIn")
                .route("headers['replyChannel']")
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "tcpOut")
    public TcpSendingMessageHandler tcpOutboundAdapter() {
        TcpSendingMessageHandler adapter = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
        adapter.setConnectionFactory(tcpServerFactory());
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpNetServerConnectionFactory tcpServerFactory() {
        TcpNetServerConnectionFactory serverFactory = new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(6060);
        serverFactory.setSerializer(TcpCodecs.lengthHeader2());
        serverFactory.setDeserializer(TcpCodecs.lengthHeader2());
        return serverFactory;
    }

    // Test config

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow tcpResponseFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Tcp.inboundAdapter(tcpClientFactory()))
                .channel(MessageChannels
                        .queue("responseChannel")
                        .get())
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    TcpNetClientConnectionFactory tcpClientFactory() {
        TcpNetClientConnectionFactory tcpClientFactory = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory("localhost", 6060);
        tcpClientFactory.setSerializer(TcpCodecs.lengthHeader2());
        tcpClientFactory.setDeserializer(TcpCodecs.lengthHeader2());
        return tcpClientFactory;
    }
```

TcpToQueueHandler:

```
    public Message<String> handleTcpIn(Message<String> message) {
        String payload = message.getPayload();
        String replyChannel;

        try {
            isValid(payload); // throws Exception if payload is invalid
            replyChannel = Processor.OUTPUT;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid payload, sending to nullChannel");
            replyChannel = "nullChannel";
        }

        return MessageBuilder
                .withPayload(payload)
                .setHeader("replyChannel", replyChannel)
                .build();
    }
```

QueueToTcpHandler:

```
    public Message<String> handleQueueIn(Message<String> messageIn) {
        String payload = messageIn.getPayload();
        String replyChannel;

        try {
            isValid(payload); // throws Exception if payload is invalid
            replyChannel = "tcpOut";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid payload, sending to nullChannel");
            replyChannel = "nullChannel";
        }

        return MessageBuilder
                .withPayload(payload)
                .setHeader("replyChannel", replyChannel)
                .build();
    }
```

Test:

```
    @Autowired
    private TcpNetClientConnectionFactory tcpClientFactory;

    @Autowired
    private Processor processor;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("responseChannel")
    private QueueChannel responseChannel;

    @Test
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void validPayloadSentToTcpConnection() throws Exception {
        Message<String> requestMessage = MessageBuilder
                .withPayload("This is a valid payload")
                .build();
        tcpClientFactory.start();
        tcpClientFactory.getConnection().send(requestMessage);

        Message<String> responseMessage = MessageBuilder
                .withPayload(requestMessage.getPayload())
                .setHeader(IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID, tcpClientFactory.getConnection().getConnectionId())
                .build();

        processor.input().send(responseMessage);

        Message<String> received = (Message<String>) responseChannel.receive(2000);
        assertNotNull(received);
    }
```

The message routes correctly to the tcpOut channel, but the TcpSendingMessageHandler throws the outbound socket error. I'm confused because I'm setting the ip_connectionId. What am I missing?

Comment: Any chances to have some simple project from you to let us to play with? I'm not sure though why do you have a `Tcp.inboundAdapter()` on the client side and try to send something back when it is not a request-reply (gateway) scenario...

Comment: Sure, https://github.com/chris-jansson/tcp-to-queue.

Comment: I'm testing the response flow, so the inbound adapter is there to receive the response over the TCP connection. The message flow should be processor.input() -->queueToTcpHandler-->tcpOut-->tcpOutboundAdapter-->tcpResponseFlow

Comment: @artembilan any update on this? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, tomorrow. We are busy on some conference today

Comment: @ChrisJansson could you please share the code again? github.com/chris-jansson/tcp-to-queue is not working. I have a similiar problem and could use some help! Thanks

Comment: @LeoPucciBr unfortunately I don't have the code anymore. But the issue was that I was mixing up the connection IDs stored by the client connection factory with the ones stored by the server connection factory. Once I made sure to store / retrieve the correct connection ID, it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is indeed with your connection id. You're setting the incorrect one.
Both the `TcpNetClientConnectionFactory` and `TcpNetServerConnectionFactory` have their own list of available connections.
The same connection will however have a different id, eg.
`localhost:6060:55690:6855ca59-4c09-4f4c-9c3b-98415f60c276` (client) and `localhost:55690:6060:ae60f5a3-f797-4315-99f9-b35905faaaf9` (server).
You asked for a connection on the client side, set the id on the message that would arrive in `QueueToTcpHandler`, and tried to send it over TCP using a non-existing connection from the server.

I created a PR on the repository so you have the changes I made in order to get it to work.

Hope that clarifies the problem you had! :)